# IE11 cannot use import * as XXX from XXX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer, d3.js

IE11 cannot use import * as XXX from XXX, for example:[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msagB.png)

ie11 show error:[ie11 show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXqFw.png).this works perfectly in chrome and FF, but not works in IE11

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reformat your post. This will make it so that viewers can find you an answer much easier

Comment: How do you know the error is due to `import * as`? I suggest that you can refer to [this article](https://jacklyons.me/how-to-fix-vuejs-not-working-in-ie11/) about how to support IE 11 in Vue app. If it still doesn't work, please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **run and reproduce** the issue, so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: @YuZhou  After testing, I found it is not the reason why IE11 does not recognize "import * as". Now I switch to the V5 version，it's works in IE11. then how does D3V6 run on IE？

Comment: It depends on the elements and attributes your code uses. You need to add different polyfills for specific features you want to support in IE.